# Using a css in javafx is causing a huge memory usage for real time candle stick chart

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx-2, candlestick-chart

I have followed [ensemble sample](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) of javafx and tried to create a candle stick chart.

It loads a css file ensemble2.css using this line of code

```
getStylesheets().add((CandleStickChart.class.getResource(
                    "ensemble2.css")
                    .toExternalForm()));
```

but when I profile my application (which is adding one candle every 100 ms ) it is using around 2 GigaBits of memory but when I removed CSS it is using only half this memory.

What could be possible reason and how can it be improved.

Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad (formerly [_not constructive_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732/163188)); there are myriad reasons for examples using the two frameworks to have different [profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I didn't follow you here. What two framework are you talking about. Please do not mix two question. This question is solely on javafx and other one is on jfree.

Comment: My error; this is a JavaFX question; it still needs an example and profile results.